# Optimising a Prolog script

Tags: list, prolog

I'm new to Prolog, we're using in University, and it was asked to define a sainthood, I wrote a quick script that is answering to requirements:

```
    % List of Saints taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_saints

    % Rule to define sainthood
    saint(X) :-
       human(X),
       has_faith(X),
       died(X),
       made_miracles(X).

    % List of humans
    human('Abadiu of phoenix').
    human('Abakuh').
    human('Abamun of Tarnut').
    human('Saint Phoenix').
    human('Fabrizio').
    human('Bob').

   % List of believer
   has_faith('Abadiu of phoenix').
   has_faith('Abakuh').
   has_faith('Abamun of Tarnut').
   has_faith('Saint Phoenix').
   has_faith('Bob').

   % List of died
   died('Abadiu of phoenix').
   died('Abakuh').
   died('Abamun of Tarnut').
   died('Saint Phoenix').

   made_miracles('Abadiu of phoenix').
   made_miracles('Abakuh').
   made_miracles('Abamun of Tarnut').
   made_miracles('Saint Phoenix').
```

But I would like to improve the code and learning Prolog at the same time, I used:

```
human(X,['Abadiu of phoenix','Abakuh','Abamun of Tarnut','Saint Phoenix','Fabrizio']).
```

or

```
human(['Abadiu of phoenix','Abakuh','Abamun of Tarnut','Saint Phoenix','Fabrizio']).
```

In order to create an array of humans but without success, where I need to look in order to improve the mentioned code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to Prolog too but I suppose you need `findall/3`.

Given the following facts

```
% List of humans
human('Abadiu of phoenix').
human('Abakuh').
human('Abamun of Tarnut').
human('Saint Phoenix').
human('Fabrizio').
human('Bob').
```

you can define the following clause

```
humanList(L) :-
  findall(U, human(U), L).
```

that unify, in `L`, the list `['Abadiu of phoenix','Abakuh','Abamun of Tarnut','Saint Phoenix','Fabrizio','Bob']`

p.s.: what do you call "array", in Prolog is called "list"